# Class Versus Struct

Tags: c++, object-oriented

In C++ and other influenced languages there is a construct called Structure (`struct`), and another called the `class`. Both are capable of holding functions and variables. Some differences are:

1. Class is given memory in the heap and `struct` is given memory in the stack (remark: this is wrong for C++, but maybe correct in what the OP called "influenced languages")
2. Class variable are private by default and in `struct` they are public

My question is: was the `struct` somehow abandoned for Class? If so, why? Other than the differences above, a `struct` can do all the same things that a class does. So why abandon it?

Comment: by abandon I meant why one is used over the other.

Comment: your question answers this itself I think.

Comment: The difference between classes and structs is language-dependent. Some lessons from C++ do not really apply to C#.

Comment: Uhhhh. In C++ you can allocate objects on the stack or heap. Wherever you want.

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong. Stack vs. heap has *nothing* to do with the difference.

Comment: @Aaronaught but in C# is has everything to with stack vs heap which is why you talk about this as a general concept between languages.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen no http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: @jk. I know that structs go inline where ever you put them in C#. My point is the semantics of structs are totally different from c++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not abandoned at all. In fact, even modern languages like C# which make heavy use of `class` still offer you `struct`. As for when it's useful to choose one over the other, I refer you to this article:

[Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

Quoted from the MSDN article:

> Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.
>
> Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>     (integer, double, and so on).
> - It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Comment: This answer is really misguided as .Net/C# struct/class meaning is different than C++ one: they use the same name but have different semantic depending on the language!!! In C++ there is almost no difference between struct and class and the question is totally wrong on the first point, which is right in c# and D but not in c++. So the link to this article, which is about .Net, is really really wrong. It's not C++!

Comment: @Klaim technically its not right for C# either (structs can be on the heap) The important distinction in C# is between value semantics and reference semantics, a distinction that C++ doesn't need as it can have values or references for anything

Answer (score 19):

You are mistaken about C++: the only significant difference between class and struct is the default access specifier difference.  Struct and class are for all intents and purposes synonyms, I believe struct is kept around for backwards compatibility to C.

Comment: Not only. Struct is a good choice when you just want to dump a bunch of data in one object and don't add any behaviour to it.

Comment: @quant: That's a *terrible* reason to use a struct. I really hope that comment was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @Aaronaught Why? My view on the usage of struct is fairly standard, see this answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c/54596#54596

Comment: @quant: Objects with data but no behaviour are an OO antipattern. In C it wouldn't really matter, but in C++ (or worse, C#) it raises red flags about the program design.

Comment: @Aaronaught How do you return multiple values then? Say, a procing model returns the clean price, dirty price, and sum of accrued payments.

Comment: @quant: Those sound like immutable values to me. Class or struct, they should be hidden behind read-only properties/getters, which is at least some kind of behaviour. Also, I admit I'm not in quants, but AFAIK, the clean price is derived from the dirty price, so why would a caller want both?

Comment: @Aaronaught Very well, we'll return a const struct. And no, clean price cannot be computed from the dirty price alone. And callers usually need both.

Comment: @quant_dev - you can decide to attach some meta-meaning to a struct for your purposes (and for former C programmers one that actually does make a lot of sense), but that does not change the fact that the only difference between the struct and class keywords in C++ is the default access.

Comment: @MadKeithV On the syntactic level you're right. On the semantic level, you're wrong.

Comment: "Struct is a good choice when you just want to dump a bunch of data in one object and don't add any behaviour to it.": But apart from the switched default visibility (public / private), there is no semantic difference between class and struct. So struct (or class) could simply be dropped from the language (one construct does not add any expression power wrt to the other).

Answer (score 2):

the language D has created a greater distinction between class and struct

a struct in d is nothing but a stack allocated data record with some functions you can call on it (there is *no option* for inheritance unless you use a enum + union setup i.e. implement the polymorfism yourself) that is passed by value

a class is like we are used to: virtual functions, heap allocation, (single) inheritance, passed by ref